# Issue with connmactl in beaglebone green wireless

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, beagleboneblack, connman

I have connected my beaglebone green wireless to internet with connmactl but i have to do this to achieve it.

```
ubuntu@arm:~$ connmanctl 
Error getting VPN connections: The name net.connman.vpn was not provided by any connmanctl> disable wifi
Disabled wifi
connmanctl> enable wifi
Enabled wifi
connmanctl> scan wifi
Error /net/connman/technology/wifi: No carrier
connmanctl> disable wifi
Disabled wifi
connmanctl> enable wifi
Enabled wifi
connmanctl> scan wifi
Scan completed for wifi
connmanctl> exit
```

I want that the beaglebone automatically connect to internet when i login in with ssh. Is that posible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My BBGW are able to connect to internet automatically (once configured).  The following example comes from /etc/network/interfaces of the Debian 8 image for BBGW.

```
connmanctl> tether wifi disable
connmanctl> enable wifi
connmanctl> scan wifi
connmanctl> services  // will list the detected 2.4 GHz WAP
connmanctl> agent on
connmanctl> connect wifi_*_managed_psk  // specify WAP to connect 
connmanctl> quit
```

Once you have the AP working, connman will remember it and connect at boot.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This issue also occurred with me due to some reason it happens.
It was solved with inserting new image in Beagle-bone.